# неправильно форматируется таблица создаваемая рекурсивно

Tags: flutter

собственно проблема в том, что если в колонке "значение" выводить String, то все работает корректно, если я вывожу туда объект, то он не учитывает размеры вложенного виджета(по крайней мере я так понимаю)

```
class ProductParamsTable extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> productParams;

  ProductParamsTable({super.key, required this.productParams});

  Widget buildTableCell(dynamic value) {
    if (value is Map<String, dynamic>) {
      // Если значение - это Map, создаем вложенный ProductParamsTable
      return ProductParamsTable(productParams: value);
    } else {
      // В противном случае, отображаем значение как текст
      return Text(value.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Параметр'),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Значение'),
        ),
      ],
      rows: productParams.entries.map((entry) {
        return DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text(entry.key)),
            DataCell(
              buildTableCell(entry.value),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: собственно проблема]